# Как сделать, чтобы бот телеграм отправлял случайное изображение из папки и запоминал его?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, telebot, бот

Делаю бота для тренировки к ОГЭ и нужно что бы при нажатии на InlineKeyboard кнопку он присылал картинку и в случае чего к определенной картинке выдавал ответ именно на неё, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если вы делаете бота, значит уже имеется какой-то код. Здесь помогут найти и исправить ошибки, но за Вас делать всю работу никто не будет.

Comment: @mrBars1k в большинстве случаев, когда сообщение начинается со слов "делаю бота..." - это означает максимум две вещи: `1) я тут видео на ютубе посмотрел` и `2) установил PyCharm и даже пару раз запускал`, но не более того. Ну в каких то редких случаях это код, выданный ChatGPT )))

Answer (score 0):

Создай словарь какой-нибудь, типо такого

```py
data = {'1.jpg':'Ответ: Питон учить в целом так-то норм решение'}
```

С помощью os получаешь все файлы в конкретной директории с файлами
С помощью random.choice тянешь какой-то один и сохраняешь её в переменную

```py
>>> a = ['1','2','3']
>>> el = random.choice(a)
```

и достаёшь нужный ответ из словаря, ключ ты только, что  получил

```py
data.get(el)
```